# Getting started with UNO and Java with Open/LibreOffice

Tags: java, eclipse, openoffice.org, libreoffice, uno

I just started to develop a Java project using LibreOffice's 4.0.1 UNO SDK, aaaand... I'm pretty much stuck right at the beginning. I think the same can be applied if I used OpenOffice.org instead of LibreOffice, so any help is appreciated.

I'm using Eclipse Juno 4.2 and I created a "Hello World"-like project. I added the `/program` directory to the classpath (added as an external class folder), and right at the beginning this line of code

```
XComponentContext ctx = Bootstrap.bootstrap();
```

throws an `UnsatisfiedLinkError` exception with the following stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jpipe in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.star.lib.util.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryLoader.java:50)
    at com.sun.star.lib.connections.pipe.PipeConnection.<clinit>(PipeConnection.java:48)
    at com.sun.star.lib.connections.pipe.pipeConnector.connect(pipeConnector.java:110)
    at com.sun.star.comp.connections.Connector.connect(Connector.java:114)
    at com.sun.star.comp.urlresolver.UrlResolver$_UrlResolver.resolve(UrlResolver.java:108)
    at com.sun.star.comp.helper.Bootstrap.bootstrap(Bootstrap.java:301)
    at xx.test.unotest.UnoTest.main(UnoTest.java:16)
```

There's even a `try/catch` surrounding the instruction but it's not triggered.

I can't find decent documentation about getting started with UNO, so I don't know what went wrong. The SDK is installed and the environment variables are configured.

Am I missing something?

**Edit**: I'using Windows 7 64 bit. Maybe this has something to do with the problem.

Comment: Try out the following connection: `-accept=socket,host=localhost,port=8100;urp;StarOffice.ServiceManager`

From http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.phtml?t=27578

Comment: @zachlatta Sadly, I get the same result.

Comment: Are your Java environment variables set correctly?

Comment: @zachlatta I'd say yes, but I don't get where I can look to check if something is wrong.

Comment: Reading from that same forum thread, it looks like they had success with `-accept=socket,host=localhost,port=8100;urp;`. Let me know if that works.

Comment: @zachlatta Yeah, I tried that too, but I get the same result.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, that's it, the library jpipe.dll wasn't found in the directories listed in the `PATH` environment variable. I had to add the path LibreOffice 4.0/URE/bin to that.

Adding the path to the `java.library.path` wouldn't work.

So, after a *very* annoying SDK installation, which *required* a GNU make tool that I won't use and forced me to install MinGW, and a crappy zip tool that couldn't simply be found since the mirrors from info-zip.org (the source given by api.libreoffice.org) are *all down*, I *still* had these stupid and undocumented problems.

Once this was solved, the 64 bit thing *was* actually a problem, since jpipe.dll is a 32 bit only library and couldn't be loaded, so I had to switch to a 32 bit JDK/JRE in order to make it work.

Man. I can do without some interface user-friendliness, but this is just making the life of a developer unnecessarily hard!

This is why open source software sometimes sucks.

Comment: add `/usr/lib/ure/lib` to classpath (for `libjpipe.so`) on linux

Comment: Tested on: Linux Mint 18.3 Sylvia.
Adding this parameter solves problem: -Djava.library.path="/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib:/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/"

Comment: Thank you guys - workling now on linux mint 20.3.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using 32 bit of libreoffice then the u need to switch 32 but of jdk to work.Otherwise download the latest version of libreoffice of 64bit

Answer (score 1):

In MacOS the libpipe library is located at `/Applications/LibreOffice.app/Contents/Frameworks/libjpipe.jnilib`. So you need to run Java like this.

```
java -cp \
  '.:/Applications/LibreOffice.app/Contents/MacOS/:any-other-jars.jar' \
  -Djava.library.path=/Applications/LibreOffice.app/Contents/Frameworks \
   com.example.YourAppClass
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to link the libjpipe.so library to `lib` directory inside of your project:

```
ln -s /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/libjpipe.so your_project/lib/
```

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu 18.04 I was able to solve the issue by adding **libjpipe.so** to this location file:///usr/lib/jni/libjpipe.so

You can get this file from /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/libjpipe.so if you have installed libre office.

This should solve the issue.